# Trying to install UWP app locally on a Windows 10 tab through Add-AppDevPackage (Windows PowerShellscript)

Tags: xaml, uwp

Hi i'm trying to install  UWP app locally on a windows 10 tab through Add-AppDevPackage (Windows PowerShellscript).It's run perfectly on windows 10 desktop same through Add-AppDevPackage (Windows PowerShellscript).
But it's giving error and not installing .how to resolve that issue..Here is the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YjUu.jpg)

Comment: I would try some of these suggestions: Error: Registration of the app failed

Another thing can go wrong is that you have an older windows version on the tablet. Look at this how to change this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn986903.aspx

Comment: If you have already previous version of this app installed on your PC, uninstall it and try again.